# Blazor WASM in .NET 4.7 MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Is it at all possible to drop Blazor WASM components into an old MVC app which is on .NET 4.7?

Can Blazor WASM components be exported as custom elements similar to in Angular?

For now, I want to avoid having to do a full upgrade of the app to .NET 5 if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blazor has introduced support for [Custom elements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-rc-1/#blazor-custom-elements) and can [generate Angular or React components](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-rc-1/#generate-angular-and-react-components-using-blazor).

Answer (score 4):

I found these articles which have guides and code samples which illustrate how to host Blazor WASM on an ASP.NET web application targeting .NET Framework.

1. [Using Blazor Wasm with .NET Framework MVC or another old/external site](https://medium.com/@santiagoc_33226/using-blazor-wasm-with-net-framework-mvc-or-another-old-external-site-7fc0884fcfca)
   Code repository: https://github.com/elgransan/BlazorWasmWithNetFrameworkMVC
   Notice the multiple branches for different options and features.
2. [Using Blazor WebAssembly in the old ASP.NET](https://gaevoy.com/2019/11/19/blazor-in-old-aspnet.html)
   Code repository: https://github.com/gaevoy/Gaev.BlazorOnAspNet
   Notice the pull requests with additional improvements.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for Blazor in .NET Framework web applications.

If a full upgrade is something you can't consider you might look at https://github.com/VisualReCode/Cocoon - this allows creating a reverse-proxy site on top of a Framework website with pass through from the new site to the old.